# French Quotation marks problem

Tags: google-docs

I'm using Google docs and write in French. Therefore the quotation marks I need are : «…» but Google docs only shows me the English ones: “…”. Does anyone know how to replace them by default by the French ones?

Comment: What is the layout of the keyboard that you are using? What is the language of your Google account? Have to set Google Documents to use French?

Answer (score 1):

You can force the character you need with a combination of ALT and numeric keys *(with the numpad, not the digits above the letters)*.

Here are the codes you need :

```
 ALT+0139 : ‹
 ALT+0155 : ›
 ALT+0171 : «
 ALT+0187 : »
 ALT+0145 : ‘
 ALT+0146 : ’
 ALT+0147 : “
 ALT+0148 : ”
```

Keep the ALT key while you're typing the digits, then release, the character will then be written.

You can also copy / paste from the Character tool from Windows, or a website that has them all mapped.

And if you want to go into Google Docs settings, you can go to « **Tools** › **Preferences** ».

There uncheck « *use curly quotes* », they will be written in the neutral style.

You can even add rules to replace “ with « and ” with » for an automatic replacement as you type.
If you have already typed most of your text, then just do a search & replace with the specified chars above.